# Linq getting count with condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I can get a count in test1 below, but when I try to get a count with a condition, like in test2, I get this error:

The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.8

```
        var test1 = query
             .GroupBy(g => new { g.CreationTime.Year, g.CreationTime.Month, g.CreationTime.Day })
             .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Year).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Month).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Day)
             .Select(g => new {
                 Key = g.Key.Month,
                 Count = g.Count()
             });


        var test2 = query
             .GroupBy(g => new { g.CreationTime.Year, g.CreationTime.Month, g.CreationTime.Day })
             .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Year).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Month).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Day)
             .Select(g => new {
                 Key = g.Key.Month,
                 Count = g.Count(x => g.Key.Month == 1)
             });
```

Comment: That error belongs to Entity Framework. You should specify what version you are currently using.

Comment: Did you try the same query without `string.Format`

Comment: Yes, I just removed the string.format, and it looks like it only occurs when I add a condition to the count, the multiple counts isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is limitation of EF Core. But good news that you can emulate this query by `Sum` aggregation function.

```
var test = 
   from q in query
   group q by new 
     {
        q.CreationTime.Year, 
        q.CreationTime.Month, 
        q.CreationTime.Day
     } into g
   select new 
   {
      Key   = g.Key.Month,
      Count = g.Sum(x => x.Month == 1 ? 1 : 0)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested yet but I assume it works. I got it working by getting the count from the original query, which is a hack, but it works:  Count = query.Count(c => c.CreationTime.Month == 10 && c.CreationTime.Year == x.Key.Year && c.CreationTime.Month == x.Key.Month && c.CreationTime.Day == x.Key.Day)

Comment: Starting with EFC 5.0, it's no more limitation.